# How to apply click event on respective div containing same child and class name

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Two div having class name **container** containing same elements with **same class name**. Apply Jquery when that respective children are clicked.

HTML CODE

```
<div class="container">
        <input type="button" class="negative" value="-">
        <input type="button" class="qty" value="">
        <span class="txt">None</span>
        <input type="button" class="positive" value="+">
</div>
<div class="container">
    <input type="button" class="negative" value="-">
    <input type="button" class="qty" value="">
    <span class="txt">None</span>
    <input type="button" class="positive" value="+">
</div>
```

I have written Some scripts, which will hide negative input and display None when value is 0, positive input will increase a value

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var counter = 1;

    if ($('.qty').val() === 0 || $('.qty').val() === '') {
        $('.qty').hide();
        $('.txt').show();
        $('.negative').hide();
    } else {
        $('.txt').hide();
        $('.qty').show();
        $('.negative').show();
    }
    $('.positive').click(function() {
        $('.negative').show();
        $('.qty').show();
        $('.txt').hide();
        const qty = $('.qty').val();
        $('.qty').val(counter);
        counter++;
    });
    $('.negative').click(function() {
        const qty = $('.qty').val();
        if (qty > 1) {
            counter--;
            $('.qty').val(counter);
        } else {
            counter = 1;
            $('.negative').hide();
            $('.txt').show();
            $('.qty').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

I am not sure how to use `$(this)` in above code.

I am beginner in JS and I know this code is not efficient.
If possible make it efficient.

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm doing this in the code below by using `.parent().find()`.  This can be brittle though if you rearrange your layout, so just be careful with it.  You'd be better off giving a `data` attribute to the elements and modifying them that way.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("input").click(function() {
      let clickAction = $(this).val();
      console.log($(this).val());
      let displayElement = $(this).parent().find("input.qty");
      let currentval = +$(displayElement).val();
      
      //you could use eval to make this look cleaner, but eval is often frowned upon
      if (clickAction == "+") {
         currentval++;
      } else if (clickAction == "-") {
         currentval--
      }
      $(displayElement).val(currentval);
   })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
        <input type="button" class="negative" value="-">
        <input type="button" class="qty" value="0">
        <span class="txt">None</span>
        <input type="button" class="positive" value="+">
</div>
<div class="container">
    <input type="button" class="negative" value="-">
    <input type="button" class="qty" value="0">
    <span class="txt">None</span>
    <input type="button" class="positive" value="+">
</div>
```

Comment: Thankyou So much. You answered exact what I needed, remaining hiding things I can manage. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: At that time I am not able to vote up due to less reputations. Thanks again :)